# Fail to create relationship class

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, arccatalog, relationship-class, standard-license-level

I am trying to make a relationship class between two tables, but I get this message at the end:

`Failed to create the specified relationship class`

Can you tell me why?

---

Sorry I wasn't more precise: I use ArcEditor licence level, ArcGIS 10.0 version, and we're talking about a file geodatabase. I have a table for "ducts" and a table for "cables". A "duct feature" may have several "cable features", the forein key is the ID of the ducts. It's a one-to-many simple relationship.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is along the lines of "my car won't start, can you tell me why?". More information is needed otherwise no one will answer for fear of absolutely wasting their time

Comment: How about starting with the basics: arcgis license level (AV, AE, AI); arcgis version #; geodatabase type (SDE, fgdb, pgdb)?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more precise:- I use ArcEditor licence level, ArcGIS 10.0 version, and we're talking about a file geodatabase. I have a table for "ducts" and a table for "cables". A "duct feature" may have several "cable features", the forein key is the ID of the ducts. It's a one-to-many simple relationship.

Comment: I have the same issue.
I am using ArcGIS 10.5. I am working to a personal geodatabase (.mdb) and I tried to create a relationship, composite, one to many between 2 tables( Duct ans Subduct) and is not working.
Could be the same issue with the ArcGIS version?

Answer (score 2):

Table to table relationship classes are not supported in ArcGIS 10.0!  I was trying to do the exact same thing and an ESRI rep filled me in that it simply isn't possible.  Only feature class to table relationships are supported (at version 10.0).

Comment: Surprisingly,after several attempts I was able to create a table to table relationship class in arcgis.10, but this time it was a composite one to many relationship not a simple one. so probably this was "the thing
", I don't know.

Comment: I've done a Many-to-Many relationship, which uses a 'junction table' that links keys from tables on either end, but it only works in one direction.  It seems like table-to-table may be possible, but you should expect some 'Weird' things to happen as a result.